# Problema em conversão de data (DD/MM/YYYY para YYYY-MM-DD) com 'pd.to_datetime()' - Python

Tags: python, pandas

Estou iniciando no mundo do Python e estou tentando desenvolver um código simples para identificar o período de expiração de certificados digitais onde trabalho (é um projeto pessoal, mas aproveitando um problema real).
Consegui extrair os dados do servidor de chaves e transformá-los em um dataframe, porém quando tento converter a coluna "valido_ate" para um formato de data (pd.to_datetime()), a fim realizar cálculos com ela, reparei que em alguns casos o formato fica diferente (não são em todas as linhas desta coluna que isto aconteceu).

Repare que no campo "valido_de", que possui o mesmo código e a mesma fonte de dados isto não aconteceu.

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Observação: este é basicamente o meu primeiro código, não trabalho na área de desenvolvimento, então por favor relevem a questão de "clean code" por enquanto, um dia chego lá hehe :)

```
#Imports
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

#URL
url = requests.get("url_interna", verify=False)
url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
html = list(soup.children)[3]

#Variáveis
certificates = soup.find(id="tblCertificates")
title_name = soup.find('td', class_='tdTitle tdTitleName').text
title_subject = soup.find('td', class_='tdTitle tdTitleSubject').text
title_valid_from = soup.find('td', class_='tdTitle tdTitleValidFrom').text
title_valid_to = soup.find('td', class_='tdTitle tdTitleValidTo').text
title_status = soup.find('td', class_='tdTitle tdTitleStatus').text
body_name = soup.find(class_="tdBodyName")
body_subject = soup.find(class_="tdBodySubject").get_text()
body_valid_from = soup.find(class_="tdBodyValidFrom").get_text()[14:24]
body_valid_to = soup.find(class_="tdBodyValidTo").get_text()[14:24]
body_status = soup.find(class_="tdBodyStatus").get_text()
lista_names = certificates.select(".tdBodyName")
lista_subject = certificates.select(".tdBodySubject")
lista_valid_from = certificates.select(".tdBodyValidFrom")
lista_valid_to = certificates.select(".tdBodyValidTo")
lista_status = certificates.select(".tdBodyStatus")
names = [pt.get_text() for pt in lista_subject]
valido_de = [pt.get_text()[14:24] for pt in lista_valid_from]
valido_de = pd.to_datetime(valido_de)
valido_ate = [pt.get_text()[14:24] for pt in lista_valid_to]
valido_ate = pd.to_datetime(valido_ate)
status = pd.to_datetime('today') - valido_ate

data = {
'nome': names,
'valido_de': valido_de,
'valido_ate': valido_ate,
'status': status
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cert_ativos = df['status'] <= '1 days'
cert_expirados = df['status'] >= '1 days'

def corrigir_nomes(nome): #Função para remover o CPF do campo "nome"
    nome = nome.replace('0', '').replace('1', '').replace('2', '').replace('3', '').replace('4','').replace('5','').replace('6','').replace('7','').replace('8', '').replace('9', '').replace(':','')
    return nome
def true_false(data): #Função para transformar True/False em Expirado/Ativo
    data = data.replace('True', 'Expirado').replace('False', 'Ativo')
    return data
df['nome'] = df['nome'].apply(corrigir_nomes)
df['status'] = df['status'].apply(true_false)
```

Comment: Para os "down votes", como é minha primeira publicação, seria interessante um feedback para tentar entender o que estou fazendo de errado para que possa corrigir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de algumas tentativas, consegui resolver o problema forçando o formato durante a conversão com `pd.to_datetime()`:

Anterior: `valido_ate = pd.to_datetime(valido_ate)`

Correto: `valido_ate = pd.to_datetime(valido_ate, format='%d/%m/%Y')`

Obs.: funcionou no meu caso pois o formato da data de onde estava buscando estas informações era dd/mm/aaaa, então ele "entendeu" que deveria manter esta estrutura para a conversão.

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score -1):

Tive este mesmo problema hoje e a solução foi parecida com a sua.
No entanto, no meu caso eu estava usando `format = '%d/%m/%y'`.
Ao alterar para `format = '%d/%m/%Y'`, o código funcionou corretamente.